# What is a good set of default settings to use for GC logging in Java 9+?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-9

Prior to Java 9 I was familiar with a set of "mandatory" (as recommended in [Optimizing Java](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/optimizing-java/9781492039259/ch08.html#pracjavaperf-CHP-8)) flags for GC logging that I would enable for instances of a JVM. These were:

```
-Xloggc:gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
```

With Java 9 and the introduction of [Unified GC Logging](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/271) is are there any recommendations for an equivalent set of "mandatory" GC logging settings?

Comment: `-XX:+MagicOptionFittingAllNeedsWithoutFurtherContext`

Comment: Thanks for the sarcasm, it was really helpful. All I'm asking is are there a sensible set of default GC logging settings that provide useful output regardless of context. A valid answer could be none however in the past people have suggested a good starting point that ticks many boxes for analysing GC behaviour.

Comment: How do you determine usefulness of the output? Without an actual problem to solve, the most useful output is *none*. If the linked statement that “Every serious application should always … generate a GC log” was true, generating such logs was the default. But it’s not. There is no point in generating files no-one ever looks at. If you were one of those guys reading them, you already knew what you need. If you were planning to analyze them with tools, generating the output the tools can parse, was the best option. Since you are going to do neither, the generated logs are just wasting space…

Comment: So I kind of said what I needed, help translating my previous settings for Java 8 to equivalent for 9+, or just general advice. The logs can indeed then be fed into tools which parse the 9+ standard GC logging format.  As part of a team supporting a platform with a large amount of JVM based workloads it's useful for us to have GC logs enabled for certain apps so that as and when issues occur, we have some of the information we need to debug. These "default" logs may not always have the answers but the where the overhead/waste of logging isn't an issue it makes sense.

Comment: So when you use “tools which parse the 9+ standard GC logging format”, there’s not much sense in trying to emulate pre Java 9 behavior. Instead, use the options which provide data, these tools can handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The corresponding flags to use for GC logging with Java-9 and above would be:

```
-Xlog:gc* -Xlog:age*=debug
```

Reference - [Enable Logging with the JVM Unified Logging Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#JSWOR-GUID-BE93ABDC-999C-4CB5-A88B-1994AAAC74D5)